# Set a max value for a custom field in salesforce of type number

Tags: object, salesforce, field

I have created a custom field in a custom object of type Number(2,1) in salesforce. Please let me know how set a max value for this field.

Answer (score 1):

You should create the trigger, which will fire when new record is created, select latest record, do query like this [select number_field from object order by id desc limit 1]. Get latest number_field and increase the value.

So you'll get max value.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to enforce a max value for a field would be through a Validation Rule on that field (Validation Rules are set on object). For example, to set a max value of 20 on a field called My_Field__c:

FORMULA: My_Field__c > 20
ERROR MESSAGE: My Field cannot be greater than 20.